# Dynamically list all members of a class

Tags: c++, reflection, class, member

Is it possible in C++ to dynamically (during run-time) get a list of all members of the class?

Comment: i think the dynamic-programming tag might be misleading

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, not without doing some work at compile time first manually. C++ has no reflection. Qt works around this with its `moc` system which scans your source files and generates meta data for all Qt (and inherited) classes